# How to send multiple files to kafka producer using akka stream in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka-stream

I am trying to send multiple data to kafka producer using akka stream , meanwhile I wrote the producer itself , but struggling of how to use akka-streamIO in order to get multiple files which will be the data I want to send to my kafka Producer this is my code:

```
 object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val file = Paths.get("233339.8.1231731728115136.1722327129833578.log")
//    val file = Paths.get("example.csv")
//
//    val foreach: Future[IOResult] = FileIO.fromPath(file)
//      .to(Sink.ignore)
//      .run()

    println("Hello from producer")

    implicit val system:ActorSystem = ActorSystem("producer-example")
    implicit val materializer:Materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val producerSettings = ProducerSettings(system,new StringSerializer,new StringSerializer)

    val done: Future[Done] =
      Source(1 to 955)
        .map(value => new ProducerRecord[String, String]("test-topic", s"$file : $value"))
        .runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))

    implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher
    done onComplete  {
      case Success(_) => println("Done"); system.terminate()
      case Failure(err) => println(err.toString); system.terminate()
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: When you uncomment that code, what is currently happening? Does this work for one file? What have you tried to get multiple?

Comment: it does working for one file for multiple files it does not work... 
This is what I found:

val file = Paths.get("example.csv")

val foreach: Future[IOResult] = FileIO.fromPath(file)
  .to(Sink.ignore)
  .run()

Comment: And what if you try multiple threads. One per file?

Comment: what do u mean? I just want to be able to send a different source from what I am using now and be able to send my 955 log files which are text files via Kafka producer...

Comment: Right... `new FileSenderThread(filename).start()`... Will start create it's own producer from a file

Answer (score 0):

Given multiple file names:

```
val fileNames : Iterable[String] = ???
```

It is possible to create a `Source` that emits the contents of the files concatenated together using `flatMapConcat`:

```
val chunkSize = 8192

val chunkSource : Source[ByteString, _] = 
  Source.apply(fileNames)
        .map(fileName => Paths get fileName)
        .flatMapConcat(path => FileIO.fromPath(path, chunkSize))
```

This will emit fixed size  `ByteString` values that are all `chunkSize` length, except for possibly the last value which may be smaller.

If you want to breakup the lines by some delimiter then you can use [`Framing`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Framing$.html):

```
val delimiter : ByteString = ???

val maxFrameLength : Int = ???

val framingSource : Source[ByteString, _] =
  chunkSource.via(Framing.delimiter(delimiter, maxFrameLength))
```

Comment: Thanks Ramon but I have 955 log files which are text files.
I am trying to change the source of which of the data that my producer (kafka) send and I want to be able to send multiple files instead of the numbers and name of file like I did in my code. 

thanks!

Comment: @tupacshakur My solution doesn't send the names, it sends the actual contents.

Comment: Yeah I know Ramon I just wonder how can I integrate your solution into my code in order to send the data as value for kafka producer.